# Angular.js ng-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting out with Angular and I'm following CodeSchool's videos. The first part went smoothly, but when trying to replicate the "ng-repeat" part for an array, the html doesn't display the values of the objects, just the directives.

app.js:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = gems;


});

var gems = {
    {
    name: 'Dodecaherdron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: 'This is a Dodecahedron',
    canPurchase: true,
    },
    {
    name: "Pentagonal Gem",
    price: 5.95,
    description: "This is a Pentagonal Gem",
    canPurchase: true,
    }
}
})();
```

html:

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h1>{{product.name}} </h1>
        <h2>${{product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Again, the code worked when trying with a single gem as a product, but not when I added the second "Pentagonal Gem", even though I followed the video's code word-by-word to check. The html site displays exactly what is written in the html document under the h1, h2, and h3 headings. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're defining `gems` as an object – do you mean to define an array?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there's not errors in your JavaScript console. You should see *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"*

Comment: Thanks Teddy, that's exactly it. I feel very dumb now.

Comment: @Phil Brackets seems to be giving me a number of errors even when the code is working so I didn't catch it. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `gems` an [array rather than an object](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them).

```
var gems = [{
  name: 'Dodecaherdron',
  price: 2.95,
  description: 'This is a Dodecahedron',
  canPurchase: true,
}, {
  name: "Pentagonal Gem",
  price: 5.95,
  description: "This is a Pentagonal Gem",
  canPurchase: true,
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using **gem** variable as an Object, you need to make it an Array, either by running a loop to push in each Object or just wrapping your inner Object inside square brackets.

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = gems;

    var gems = [{
      name: 'Dodecaherdron',
      price: 2.95,
      description: 'This is a Dodecahedron',
      canPurchase: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Pentagonal Gem",
      price: 5.95,
      description: "This is a Pentagonal Gem",
      canPurchase: true,
    }];
  });
})();
```